# Problemas com __eq__, __lt__, etc. e o metodo remove do objeto list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tendo o seguinte problema, tenho uma classe carta e uso os metodos magicos **eq**, **ne**, **le**, **lt**, **ge**, **gt** pra poder comparar o valor de duas cartas e tambem pra poder usar a funcao sort, e pra isso funciona da maneira que eu esperava mas quando preciso usar o metodo remove de uma lista pra remover uma carta simplesmente ou remove a carta errada ou nao remove nenhuma. Segue uma parte do codigo da classe:

```
class Card(object):

def __init__(self, game, value, suit, args={}):
    super(Card, self).__init__()
    self.front = pygame.image.load("images/cards/card_{}_{}.png".format(
        suit, value)).convert()
    self.back = back.convert()
    self.image = self.front
    self.rect = self.front.get_rect(**args)
    self.sound = sounds["card_place_1"]
    self.game = game
    self.value = value
    self.suit = suit
    self.moved = False
    self.visible = True

def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.manilha == other.manilha

def __ne__(self, other):
    return self.manilha != other.manilha

def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.manilha < other.manilha

def __le__(self, other):
    return self.manilha <= other.manilha

def __gt__(self, other):
    return self.manilha > other.manilha

def __ge__(self, other):
    return self.manilha >= other.manilha

@property
def manilha(self):
    if self.image == self.back:
        return -1
    elif "4567qjka23".find(self.value) == "34567qjka2".find(
            self.game.vira.value):
        return {"diamonds": 10, "spades": 11, "hearts": 12, "clubs": 13}[
            self.suit]
    else:
        return "4567qjka23".find(self.value)
```

Comment: E onde no código está o `remove` que está dando problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é simples. O método `list.remove` busca o objeto que você passou por parâmetro na lista e remove ele. Para saber que ele encontrou o objeto correto, ele usa o método `__eq__` para comparar o objeto que foi passado com cada objeto da lista.

O problema do seu código é que o método `__eq__` retorna true para objetos diferentes. O método `manilha` usa na maioria das vezes apenas o atributo `value` para calcular o identificador do objeto, ou seja, 2 cartas com mesmo `value` e `suit` diferentes vão ser apontadas como a mesma carta (afinal elas retornam o mesmo valor no método `manilha`).

Uma solução seria olhar o suit quando as manilhas forem iguais. Por exemplo:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if self.manilha == other.manilha:
        return self.suit == other.suit
    return False
```